# In ODATA resource path I want to order by InvoiceNo in ascending order. Without using sorting method in query only using order by how it's solved?

Tags: odata

Invoice number:1,2,3,10,11,21,22,31,13

My query is:

> resourcePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SSInvoices?$Orderby=InvoiceNo asc &$filter=SoldToID eq '%@'", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"SELECTEDDEALERNO"]];

I am getting out put:1,10,11,13,2,21,22,31

Comment: that is how string sorting of numbers works